# While looping through results with $.each, how do you refer to the index of the current iteration?

Tags: jquery, loops, iterator

If I'm looping through results from a JSON call, how do I know if I'm on the first iteration?

In this example I made up the `loopIndex` variable to indicate what I'm looking for -- but it's not actually set anywhere.

How do you know where you are in the loop - which iteration you're on?

```
$.getJSON(myurl, function(data) {
  $.each(data.results, function() {
     // what's the index of this iteration?
     if(loopIndex==0){
      console.log("first iteration!");
     }

  });
});
```

Comment: Reading docs does wonders. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first parameter to the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) callback is the index, like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=paparazzi+lady+gaga&callback=?", function(data) {
  $.each(data.results, function(i, item) {
     if(i==o) {
       console.log("first iteration!");
     }
  });
});
```

The signature for [`.Query.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is:

```
jQuery.each(collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $.each(data.results, function(loopIndex) {
     .....
```

as shown in the [documentation of `jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
$.each(data.results, function(index) {
    // what's the index of this iteration?
    alert(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example

```
function emailform(rtndata) {
         $.each(rtndata.products, function (i, product) {
             $("<img/>").attr({
                   src: product.imageLargeUrl,
                   title: product.name,
                   width: 100,
                   height: 100
             }).appendTo(".images");
           $('.question').html(rtndata.title);
           if (i == 1) return false;
          });
}
```